# Super high CPU usage randomly starts when using Zoom, and doesn't end until I restart

Tags: firefox, cpu-load, zoom-meeting

**Update:** Live screenshot of when it happens

[image]

[image]

So... When I'm using Zoom, most often during screen sharing, or when someone else is screensharing, all of my cores zip up to 100%, as in the screenshot above, and everything turns really sluggish. I can make out people telling me there's an echo, and Zoom gives me that "high CPU usage is slowing down Zoom" error, but then Zoom is what's chewing through my CPUs. Even if I kill zoom, and my browser, I still have some strange sluggish behavior. I can't open apps, nothing is as responsive. It's like something goes permanently wrong.

The only way to restore normal function is to restart the machine.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Should I just throw out my computer, fly to a Caribbean island and retire?

Comment: Zoom is known  to be resource eater when the conference is active. Firefox may be too if you have opened dynamic sites (with animation, videos, big advertisement and so on) in it in foreground tab. Seems to be expected.

Comment: @NOrbert, it continues after the applications have been closed. Run "top" in the terminal. Chances are you will see a kworker process sucking up your CPU.

Comment: @N0rbert ooo, I'll try that. What would that mean?

Comment: I believe you are experiencing the same issues as the following: https://devforum.zoom.us/t/very-high-cpu-load-audio-video-problems-for-web-sdk/7937/31
Supposedly zoom are aware of this issue and are working on a fix.

Comment: Try going to `about:performance` in Firefox and double-check the culprit is indeed zoom.

Comment: @Landak Holy crap! That just made me very happy. I had no idea about:performance existed.

Comment: _Firefox_ has an issue with its processes growing incontrolably on Linux and hugging the CPU. I have experienced that serveral times myself. The nice solution is **Closing all _Firefox_ Windows**. The last resource is **Killing all _Firefox_ Processes**. It is obviously a bug in _Firefox_ because it happens even my desktops is on without any work at night time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you've got two problems going on as far as your computer is concerned:

1. Zoom is a resource hog.
2. Something in firefox is a resource hog.

I infer that what you actually mean is

3. My GUI gets laggy and I don't like it.

### 1 – "Tweaking" (breaking) the scheduler to force-limit a CPU intensive process

To deal with the former, as well as complaining loudly (and not using video backgrounds), you *may* wish to consider limiting the amount of CPU it can have. This is done in linux via control groups or [CGROUPS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt), which can effectively limit scheduling for a single group. For example, you can use CGROUPS to get the kernel to constrain processes within a CGROUP to use, let's say for example, 100 ms out of every 1000 ms (or .1s out of every 1s) of CPU time. This *will make things worse* for your Zoom experience but *might* be better over all.

To give this a go, `sudo apt install cgroup-tools libcgroup1 libcgroup-dev`, and then create a cpu-limited cgroup with

```
sudo cgcreate -g cpu:/cpulimit
```

Here, cpulimit is the group name that controls the cpu usage. Now, you have to set `cpu.cfs_period_us` and `cpu.cfs_quota_us` property on the `cpulimit` group.

In keeping with the above example, let's set 1 s or 1000000 us (microseconds) should be set to `cpu.cfs_period_us` property and 100 ms or 100000 us should be set to the `cpu.cfs_quota_us` property

```
sudo cgset -r cpu.cfs_period_us=1000000 cpulimit
sudo cgset -r cpu.cfs_quota_us=100000 cpulimit
```

To check to see that this is the case, run `sudo cgget -g cpu:cpulimit` and observe that these flags are set.

It's now the case that whatever process you add to the `cpulimit` CGROUP will, as the name suggests, be limited to using use 1/10th (100000/1000000 = 1/10 = 0.1 = 10%) of the total CPU cycles. At the very least, this probably helps quite a lot.

Now to *actually use* this and start a process, start the program or command with `cgexec` as follows:

```
sudo cgexec -g cpu:cpulimit YOUR_COMMAND
```

where `YOUR_COMMAND` can be `/path/to/zoom` or *literally anything else*.

### 2 – Finding performance hogs in Firefox

Firefox has a nifty `about:performance` page that will help you spot hungry pages. often these use a lot of javascript, display ads, or may even be so rude as to run, for example, a cryptocurrency miner without telling you. As well as killing (closing) the culprit page, one thing you might want to do to stop that happening again is taking the plunge and using a selective javascript blocker like the excellent [umatrix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/umatrix/) to prevent that happening again. Sure, it breaks some pages, but you usually learn something about the web in unblocking particular links ;-).

### 3 – Stopping your GUI from lagging the *nice* way

As well as the not-often-used cgroups to place a hard limit on processor scheduling, Linux has an inbuilt idea of process priority. For reasons of history that I would love to learn if others can educate me, Linus called this priority *niceness*. We can *renice* (or `sudo renice`) a process to make it "nicer" -- i.e. run with a higher priority. By default, users can renice processes down to a priority of `0` (and up to `19`) and root to `-20`. Lower `niceness` processes are given more priority by the scheduler. (I think the idea here is that a process that you don't *really* care about -- i.e. one that would be "nice to have" -- is given a *higher* niceness to *decrease* its priority).

For gnome, it /may/ help to `renice` the gui to a lower niceness. This is quite easy to do; e.g. `sudo renice -3 -p $(pgrep Xwayland) && sudo renice -3 -p $(pgrep gnome-shell)`. Again, similarly to the above, `nice` will start a process with a specified niceness; but here you need to specify it with a `-` beforehand -- so that `nice -10 /path/to/zoom` would start `zoom` with a niceness of `+10` (and `nice --10 /path/to/zoom` with a niceness of `-10`). This also /may/ be a better way of going about it.

Comment: nice goes back before Linux https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for being late to the party, but I have the same issues. I tracked the CPU clocking and noticed, that it was set to 400MHz, therefore all of the cores run @ 100% load.

I switch between the energy settings of my machine from power to balanced and the cores started to run at much higher clock speeds after that and fixing the issues.

I could not track down the source of the down clocking though.

Comment: Question was already answered and accepted. Not seeing where this answer adds anything.

Comment: This one just solved my problem. Fedora 37 had automatic power saving when the laptop was unplugged. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue with firefox or chrome/chromium is running in the background. Or, any else app is eating the RAM or CPU. Check the process in System Monitor and kill the process

Comment: Yup, tried this every time it happened. Nothing solved it. The CPUs wouldn't calm down even after I killed everything.

Comment: Maybe problem with CPU itself.

Comment: I think you overclocked your CPU

Comment: I must have done so inadvertently if so.